# .aspx file help

Tags: asp.net

Thank you for everyone's help so far! Have had some really helpful answers on this site so far so am hoping for one more.

What I want to create is EXACTLY this, but i'm still having problems

http://www.webonweboff.com/widgets/ajax/ajax_linked_selection.aspx

I have copied the html and javascript word for word and saved that file as index.html (but obviously with open and close html and body tags)

The file I have called ajaxServer.aspx.cs has the following code:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;
using System.Web.UI;
using System.Web.UI.WebControls;
using System.Text;

public partial class _Default : System.Web.UI.Page
{
    protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        Response.ContentType = "text/javascript";
        string id = Request.QueryString.Get("id");
        string action = Request.QueryString.Get("action");
        StringBuilder returnString = new StringBuilder();

        /* 
            Retrieve the data based on values "id" and "action"
            and build a response string in this format: 
                [{text:"...",
         * 
         * value:"...",selected:false},
                 {text...}]
            No final ";" is necessary

            For example:
        returnString.Append("[{text:\"California\",value:\"CA\",selected:false}," +
                             "{text:\"OH\",value:\"Ohio\",selected:false}," + 
                             "{text:\"NY\",value:\"New York\",selected:true}]");

        */

        Response.Write(returnString.ToString());
    }
}
```

and the file I have called ajaxServer.aspx has the following code:

```
<%@ Page Language="C#" AutoEventWireup="true" 
    CodeFile="ajaxServer.aspx.cs" Inherits="_Default" %>
```

The other (.js) files I have downloaded and saved. When I run the .html file i get the following error:

error fetching data!

url:ajaxServer.asp

method:GET

params:action=state,culture=en-us

readyState:4

status:403

headers:Server: ASP.NET Development Server/10.0.0.0
Date: Sun, 19 Jun 2011 20:39:55 GMT
X-AspNet-Version: 4.0.30319
Cache-Control: private
Content-Type: text/html; charset=utf-8
Content-Length: 2126
Connection: Close

--> Any clues anyone? And once again - thank you for all the help in advance!

Comment: Don't delete your question after it has been answered. It may help others in the future

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe you want to change your ajaxServer.aspx file so that Inherits="_Default" instead of Inherits="widgets_ajax_ajaxServer".

Comment: Hi there - thanks for the help. That error has disappeared and I am now getting another one. It says "The type or namespace 'StringBuilder' could not be found (are you missing a using detective or an assembly reference?)

Comment: add using System.Text; as using statement.

Answer (score 1):

Rename your class from _Default to widgets_ajax_ajaxServer.

Comment: Too bad there can only be one checked answer. Yours is the same answer tackled from the opposite direction.

Answer (score 0):

"(are you missing a using detective or an assembly reference?)" Means exactly what it says.

StringBuilder lives in the System.Text namespace.

So you need a

using System.Text;

declaration at the top of the class.

Comment: Thanks for that - made the change and the error disappears. When I actually open index.html though, my 2nd box has no options in it now - unlike the example in the link I am taking the code from. Any ideas on this one? Thanks again!